# Multiple key presses for one key press hotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I really don't know to create this script.

When I press "r" key I want both "r" and "w" to be pressed.

Can anyone help me script this command?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [AutoHotkey Forum post](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=40770), try:

```
~$r::Send {w}
```